# Incorrect characters at ModelBinding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, character-encoding, turkish

i have a problem i am developing an asp.net mvc project. Website is in Turkish Language. When i publish this website to IIS Turkish characters get crazy in web pages so i set globalization in my web.config as

```
<globalization fileEncoding="iso-8859-9" requestEncoding="iso-8859-9" responseEncoding="iso-8859-9"/>
```

After this Turkish characters shown correct.

But now i have another problem when i enter Turkish text to an input text and then POST to my controller action, Turkish characters get crazy again.

I tracked the http messages Turkish text POST correctly
ex: If i enter "Yücel" (ü is Turkish character) to input, i looked to HttpAnalyzer i can see that Post Data is "Yücel". When i look to my action's parameter's properties which are binded automatically by MVC, I see "YÃ¼cel".

Is there any suggestion from you to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem, what I did is,

1. Delete following element from `web.config` so default encoding (UTF-8) will be used

   `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>`
2. Delete following from my Site.Master

   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9"/>`

Answer (score 1):

In web.config requestEncoding value;

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" ...
```

must be same as in web page charset value;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

But you can also do other request enconding process by page address setting in web.config location tag setting.
Sample:

```
<configuration>
...
<location path="path/to/your/actionmethod">
    <system.web>
        <globalization requestEncoding="ISO-8859-9" responseEncoding="ISO-8859-9" />
    </system.web>
</location>
...
</configuration>
```

http://www.siimviikman.com/2012/06/12/action-based-request-encoding-in-asp-net-mvc/